# Prove that improper integral $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, improper-integrals

Here is the assignment.

> Let $f: \ ]a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be non-negative and Riemann-integrable over $[c,b]$ for every $a<c<b$. Prove that improper integral $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ converges if and only if function $c\rightarrow\int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx$ is bounded.

I am able to prove that if improper integral $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ converges, then function $c\rightarrow\int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx$ is bounded:

> $\int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx-\int_{a}^{c} f(x) dx<\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx\leq M$

However this other way around seems to be difficult. I can't even understand why is the statement true?

Comment: Could you give a definition of "restricted"?

Comment: Restricted probably isn't the correct word for it, but I mean that there exists such $M$ that $\int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx\le M$.

Comment: So probably "bounded" would be a more common term.  And I guess that $M$ doesn't depend on $c.$

Comment: Yep, bounded is what I meant! And I don't know, this is how the assignment is given to me (ofc translated from other language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function 
$$ c \mapsto \int_c^b f(x) \mathrm{dx}$$

is defined on $]a,b]$, and decreasing because $f$ is non-negative.

If you assume that this function is bounded, that implies that it has a finite limit when $c \rightarrow a$. By definition, it is equivalent to say that the improper integral
$$\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{dx}$$
converges.

Comment: "If you assume that this function is bounded, that implies that it has a finite limit", could you please explain this a bit more?

Comment: Let's consider a function $\varphi : ]a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, decreasing and bounded. Because it is bounded, $\sup_{]a,b]} \varphi$ exists and is finite. But because $\varphi$ is decreasing, this $\sup$ is necessarily equal to the limit of $\varphi$ at the left on the interval $]a,b]$. In other words, $\varphi(x)$ has a finite limit when $x \rightarrow a^+$.

Comment: Oh of course. Now it seems so simple and easy.